# GenericType not working with templates in Java

Tags: java

My code looks like this.

```
public <T> T performTask(){
    // something 
    GenericType type = new GenericType<T>(){};
}
```

This gives an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType does not specify the type parameter T of GenericType 
Can someone suggest a way to step past this error? I need to use **type** as parameter in another utility.

Comment: No idea if the raw type is the direct problem, but: `GenericType<T> type`

Comment: It won't work unless `performTask` takes a parameter that involves `T`. Also, you need `<T>` on the type declaration of `type`, too.

Comment: Can't use generics to create a `GenericType`, you have to pass in a concrete type instead of the generic type `T`, so in this case that would probably mean taking in a `GenericType` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying, the type of object you want to use, instead of T
example:

GenericType stringListType = new GenericType() {};

Useful links: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericType.html